# Error while converting from getdate() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

On command line

```
convert(varchar,getdate(),120)
```

gives below error:

> Unknown argument '04:59:42.xml'

I am saving data to an xml file. 
when I use below command,proc works perfectly.

```
convert(varchar,getdate(),112)
```

I need the file to save with time.

Comment: `04:59:42.xml` is not a valid SQL timestamp.  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I need to save data from sql into a file on the c:\ , but the file name needs to have the date and time stamp at time of creation with .xml extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a file with a colon in the name, which is [not allowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions). No way to get around that restriction. However, you can replace the colons with other characters when naming the file, e.g.

```
replace(convert(varchar,getdate(),120),':','')
```

Comment: thank you, problem solved, had to also add a replace function for the space.

Comment: @user8492887 Please click the check mark at the top of this answer to close the question.